# MdlSelect - ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

Tags: angular2-mdl, angular-mdl

I'm getting the same issue as mentioned in this 
[github issue](https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl-ext/issues/881)

I'm using the following versions:

```
"@angular-mdl/core": "^8.0.0",
"@angular-mdl/popover": "^8.0.0",
"@angular-mdl/select": "^8.0.0",
```

From the issue, it seems that this was fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl-ext/pull/1079) and was published as @angular-mdl/select:0.11.2, but I don't see that fix in version 8.

Could you please help me out with a fix for this issue on "@angular-mdl/select": "^8.0.0"

Thanks in advance.